# How to send an ArrayList of objects to other activity?

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

I want to know how to do it to make a listview in second activity

```
Person person = new Person(nome, idade, numero);

        this.list.add(person);

    int number= this.list.size();
        this.numero.setText(String.valueOf(number));

        this.item.setText("");
    }
        break;

    case R.id.btn_activity2:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
        intent.put(...here is the problem)
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way that you can send an `ArrayList` to the next activity is by creating a `bundle` like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Object", listOfObject);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

`listOfObject` should be replaced with the name of your `ArrayList`. Then, to receive the intent in your `ListActivity.class` you can do:

```
List<Person> myList= this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("Object");
```

`myList` now is a list of that object. If you receive any errors, just comment below.

Comment: Theres an error when I put the arraylist name :(

Comment: What is the error? A possible reason may be with the Object's class. Try adding `implements Parceable` to the class. So it should look like: `public class MyObject implements Parceable`.

Comment: yeah, I do it, but when I will start the second activity theres an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.ListView/com.mycompany.ListView.ListActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.mycompany.ListView.Perso

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intent.putStringArrayListExtra(your-key, ArrayList)` then get it with

`String[] arrayList = extras.getStringArrayListExtra(your-key);`